# what to change between tomcat 7.0 and tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, tomcat

My tomcat application is running well on tomcat 7.0.55 on openSUSE 13.2.

I needed to make that application work on tomcat 8.0.32 on openSUSE 13.2. I could successfully install tomcat 8.0.32.

```
tomcat@15f439e52c9e:~> java -cp lib/catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
Server built:   Feb 22 2016 11:10:58 UTC
Server number:  8.0.32.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_95-b00
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

I didn't make any changes in the folder structure or directory or application. Now, when I run it, it throws lots of errors that I am unable to figure out how to resolve. What do we need to change between those 2 versions?

```
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.975 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 22 2016 11:10:58 UTC
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.975 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.32.0
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.976 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.976 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.976 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.977 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0/jre
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.977 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_95-b00
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.977 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.978 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/tomcat
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.978 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat/
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat/
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.980 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.980 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat/temp
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.980 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat//conf/logging.properties
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.981 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
04-Mar-2016 08:48:02.981 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
04-Mar-2016 08:48:03.688 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-Mar-2016 08:48:03.750 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
04-Mar-2016 08:48:03.757 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
04-Mar-2016 08:48:03.764 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
04-Mar-2016 08:48:03.765 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
04-Mar-2016 08:48:04.402 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
04-Mar-2016 08:48:04.403 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 3307 ms
04-Mar-2016 08:48:04.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
04-Mar-2016 08:48:04.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
04-Mar-2016 08:48:04.531 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /srv/tomcat/webapps/stig.war
04-Mar-2016 08:48:06.950 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/stig]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:939)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1812)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.findParameters(StandardContext.java:3585)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.mergeParameters(StandardContext.java:5409)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5238)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 10 more

04-Mar-2016 08:48:06.955 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive /srv/tomcat/webapps/stig.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/stig]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:939)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1812)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

04-Mar-2016 08:48:06.961 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /srv/tomcat/webapps/stig.war has finished in 2,428 ms
04-Mar-2016 08:48:06.963 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /srv/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
04-Mar-2016 08:48:08.233 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1830)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.findParameters(StandardContext.java:3585)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.mergeParameters(StandardContext.java:5409)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5238)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 10 more

04-Mar-2016 08:48:08.234 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory /srv/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1830)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

04-Mar-2016 08:48:08.236 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /srv/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 1,272 ms
04-Mar-2016 08:48:08.251 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-Mar-2016 08:48:08.270 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
04-Mar-2016 08:48:08.273 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
04-Mar-2016 08:48:08.276 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3872 ms
```

Comment: Nothing unusual. Basic java jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
```

You should try to use java 1.8 instead of 1.7. The 1.8 version of keyset() method of ConcurrentHashMap changed return type http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet--.

Compare it with 1.7 version: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet--)./ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet%28%29

Comment: Ok, installing jdk 1.8. I was of the opinion that tomcat 8.0 will auto-install the jvm it can work with. Will post the results in a few minutes. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! That worked like a charm. Thanks is not enough for this. I had been struggling for this since morning. You rock!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have java 8 installed on your machine ? 
It seems like tomcat 8 is looking for a method of ConcurrentHashMap which was added since java 1.8

Edit: I just see now that you're running the jvm 7.0, try with the 8.0 and it should run fine.

Comment: Awesome! That worked like a charm. Thanks is not enough for this. I had been struggling for this since morning. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 [`ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet--) returns a [`KeySetView<K, V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView.html) while in Java 7 it returns a [`Set<K>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet()) (where `K` maps a key and `V` maps the value).

Just run Java 8 since your root cause exception expects a `KeySetView`.

Answer (score 0):

For me "tomcat 8.0.23" ran fine with JDK 1.8 and 1.7.
Seems this issue cropped in their latest release "tomcat 8.0.32".
As suggested try with JDK 8. This should help resolve.

This is a probably a documentation bug with Tomcat for the latest release; as their online [setup page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html) and also the RUNNING.txt (that comes with installable) mention that it will work with "1.7 or above". You may want to point it out to them after successful test.